Stuck on "Replaying Blocks" 100% after a forced close
I have had issues downloading Bitcoin Core, where the download would get stuck/frozen and not progress for hours.
The last time this happened I closed the Bitcoin Core window and was met with a "Bitcoin Core is shutting down" window which also just sat there for hours. After getting frustrated at no apparent lack of progress just to close down the application, I force closed it using Task Manager. On restarting the application I got the "Replaying Blocks" screen which I understand is the resyncing of the data that didn't sync properly due to the force close.
The last time I tried this, the "Replaying Blocks" reached 100% and then transitioned into the Bitcoin Core download as usual. However this time around, I reached 90% of the blockchain download at which point progress froze for several hours again. I force closed, Replaying Blocks has been running for 24 hours and I'm back at 100%, however it is not transitioning into the blockchain download as I had hoped.
What can I do please? I'm exasperated at what should have been the "easy" part of the process in setting up a node.
I'm using Windows 11 and Bitcoin Core v26.1.0
My debug.log file shows "Rolling forward" up until what looks like it could be the block height that my download had reached, and then it reverts to "Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat" every hour for the last 5 hours.

Does your node have any peers?

Have you figured out a solution to this? I'm having the same problem
